# Why doesnt Bluetooth Low Energy interfere with Wifi

Tags: ieee-802.11

so the BLE advertising channels are located at 2402Mhz, 2426Mhz and 2480Mhz.
That is so it does not interfere with the 3 wifi channels in the 2.4Ghz band.

My question is especially about the 2426Mhz advertising channel. Wifi channel 6 ranges from 2426Mhz to 2448Mhz.

My understanding is that the 2426Mhz advertising channel of BLE ranges from 2425Mhz to 2427Mhz. Is this correct?

Then it does overlap with a wifi channel and interfere? Where is my falacy in the logic? I dont get it and cant find any information about this.

Execuse my probably bad english, its not my native language.

Regards

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Wifi Channel 6 is centered at 2437Mhz and is 22Mhz large, so ranging from 2426 to 2448 as you stated (well that would rather be 23Mhz large, so not sure if it is 2427-2448 or 2426-2447).

But data is actually transmitted along a 20 MHz bandwidth, the remaining 2Mhz are used as a guard band so there's enough attenuation along the edge channel.

So there's no data transmitted at 2426 Mhz when using Wifi Channels 1 or 6 (1, 6 and 11 are the most used since they are non-overlapping)

From [Argenox](http://www.argenox.com/a-ble-advertising-primer/)

> LE uses 40 1MHz wide channels, numbered 0 to 39. Each is separated by
> 2MHz.
>
> Channels 37, 38, and 39 are used only for sending advertisement
> packets. The rest are used for data exchange during a connection.
> We’re interested in what’s happening in these 3 channels, and that’s
> what we’ll cover here.
>
> During BLE advertisement, a BLE Peripheral device transmits packets on
> the 3 advertising channels one after the other. A Central device
> scanning for devices or beacons will listen to those channels for the
> advertising packets, which helps it discover devices nearby.
>
> Channels 37, 38 and 39 are spread across the 2.4GHz spectrum on
> purpose. 37 and 39 are the first and last channels in the band, while
> 38 is in the middle. If any single advertising channel is blocked, the
> other channels are likely to be free since they’re separated by quite
> a few MHz of bandwidth.
>
> This is especially true since most other devices that interfer with
> BLE are narrow band. Channel 38 in particular was placed between Wi-Fi
> channels 1 and 6 so it avoids the Wi-Fi signal. The wide spacing of
> the advertisement channels helps BLE better manage the interference
> from Wi-Fi, Classic Bluetooth, Microwaves, Baby Monitors, etc to
> ensure that advertisements succeed.

You may find this study relevant to your question:

[Coexistence and Interference Tests on a Bluetooth Low Energy Front-End](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265602069_Coexistence_and_Interference_Tests_on_a_Bluetooth_Low_Energy_Front-End)

Here are some parts:

> On  other  hand Wi-Fi signals will  see  Bluetooth as  narrow  band
> interference and  only in  the  cases  that the Bluetooth interference
> is  not  more  than  10 dB below  the Wi-Fi signal can occasionally
> cause interference.  In most  cases Wi-Fi transmits 20 dBm and
> Bluetooth transmits 0 dBm  so  if  we  take into account the  path
> loss  Friis equation of  the  transmitted Wi-Fi signal
>
> Lpath= −27.55dB +20 log (2.4MHz ) +20×log[dist(m)]
>
> and the Link Budget equation
>
> Received  Power  (dBm)  =  Transmitted  Power  (dBm)  +  Gains (dB) −
> Losses (dB) − Lpath
>
> We get to the theoretically conclusion that only
> if the Wi-Fi  Router  is  more  than  3  meters  away  from  the
> connecting  equipment and the Bluetooth equipment is on  a  3 meters
> area  around  the  Wi-Fi equipment, that  occasionally the  Bluetooth
> signal can cause interference over the Wi-Fi

The study conclude that:

> C. Coexistence with Wi-Fi  Due  to  their  dependence  on  the  same
> band,  the  potential  for interference exists. Therefore it is
> important to  see if there  is  interference  from  Wi-Fi  on  the
> BLE  transmissions.  The  results show no effect on the Bit Error Rate
> or RSSI readout,  in  fact  the  RSSI readout shows  that  the  value
> increases. The  results  obtained  show  that  BLE  hopping  is
> effectively  avoiding  the  Wi-Fi occupy  channels,  therefore  there
> is very  good coexistence between BLE and Wi-Fi.

Comment: That clears it up thank you! Working on my bachelors thesis and its not that easy to find any information about this subject. I will take a look at the study!